# Apache multiple values within configuration

Tags: apache

**apache config file:**
(Something done by someone else)

```
start of it
Keepalive off
Timeout 60
..
..
..
rest of config
finally followed by
Keepalive on
Timeout 300
```

From the type of results it would seem that it is using the bottom values from the configuration, just wanted to make sure this is the case

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the same directive is used twice within the same scope, the last one is what is used.

Though note that some directives are lists, like `IndexOptions` or `ServerAlias`. So multiple instances of those just append to the list of options. While other directives are chains of rules, which is different than an on/off or specific name/value directive like `ErrorDocument`, `KeepAlive`, or `Timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the case should there not be any conditionals around those configurations (i.e. `<if ...>`).

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes, but sometimes no, Directory index for example is additive... http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html